# How to do periodic tasks in Python

Tags: python, events, periodic-task

I want to run a function every few seconds in Python. The function execution takes some time, and I want to include that in the waiting time as well.

I don't want to do this, because it is not strictly executed every 2 seconds and will break the periodicity (my_function also takes time to execute.)

```py
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    my_function()
```

I don't want to do this neither, because it uses too much CPU on the while loop of Thread-2.

```py
# Thread-1
While True:
    time.sleep(2)
    event.set()

# Thread-2
While True:
    if event.is_set():
        my_function()
    else:
        pass
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can consider [`ischedule`](https://pypi.org/project/ischedule/). It takes care of the function execution time right out the box, and doesn't waste CPU time for busy waiting. You can use:

```py
from ischedule import schedule, run_loop

schedule(my_function, interval=2)
run_loop()
```

Comment: Actually, after using ischedule I observed a significant increase of CPU usage compared to my former solution that was based on time.sleep() (~26% CPU vs. ~3.5% CPU).

Comment: I confirm that there is an issue.

Comment: Indeed, the dev also confirmed it, and also already fixed it. The CPU usage should again be very small.

Comment: Wow, I would not expect such a quick and great consequence of my comment. I just tested it once again, and indeed, the performance really improved! I'm impressed by this feedback loop. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the  [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) module is your friend

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using schedule itself doesn't solve the problem in the first code snippet but using it with threading solved the problem. It's just I have to start lots of threads, which seems to be fine.

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry I couldn't give a more detailed answer, I was on my phone and I'm not great at writing code on the app

Answer (score 0):

I found this code works pretty well, if I understood your question correctly.

Code broken down:

- runs func1
- runs func2
- waits 2s
- does something else after that
- waits 1s
- does it all again

```py
import threading
import time

def func1():
    print("function 1 has been called")

def func2():
    print("function 2 has been called")

def loop():
    print("loop print 1")
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func1, name="thread")
    thread.start()

    while thread.is_alive():
        continue

    if not thread.is_alive():
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2, name="thread2")
        thread2.start()

    while thread2.is_alive():
        continue
    
    time.sleep(2)

while True:
    loop()
    print("Some other thing")
    time.sleep(1)
```